# Is there an idiom for saying something that might turn out wrong or making a wild prediction?

Tags: idioms, idiom-requests

Example: I might be _______ but Brasil will win this world cup.

Comment: If slightly modified, the sentence might read like— *It might be **a shot in the dark** but I think Brazil will win this world cup.*

Comment: Idioms meaning "might turn out wrong"  or  "making a wild prediction" will generally be different.

Comment: I might be off-base, but I think . . .

Comment: I might be *going out on a limb*... but Brazil has won the world cup five times, so in this case I would say "I might be **wrong** but Brasil will win this world cup."

Comment: @Weather Vane: I think that's the one I was looking for.
In this excerpt, the idiom is used in the context of a sports analyst making a prediction about future games.
Now, a year later, I’ll go out on a limb and say the Tigers will be prepared for Howard and very aware of his every move. This time, he won’t rack up more than 50 receiving yards — and he won’t find the end zone. –USA Today

Comment: P.S. I didn't know how many world cups Brazil had won but I never mentioned which sport. ;-)

Comment: There is only one sport if you don't mention it :)

Comment: I'd go with *I might be/call me **crazy**, but Brasil will win this world cup.*

Comment: I'll take a **swag** at it:  It's a **S**ystematic **W**ild **A**ssed **G**uess!

Answer (score 1):

The Free Dictionary by [Farlex](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/go+out+on+a+limb) has this idiom:

> **go out on a limb**
>
> To do or say something that lacks evidence or support.
>
> *She really went out on a limb with that hypothesis—the facts don't support it at all.*
> *That politician went out on a limb and publicly questioned the views of his party.*
> *I don't think I'm going out on a limb by saying that everyone will like that idea.*

Also

> If you go out on a limb, you do something or say something that is different from what most people do or say and is therefore risky.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're looking for this: **A shot in the dark**

> an attempt to guess something when you have no information or knowledge about the subject and therefore cannot possibly know what the answer is

[Cambridge]

Comment: I don't think this covers an opinion of who will win the world cup. It's not as though Brazil has never won it, so it's a reasonable guess. A shot in the dark is a hunch about which you have very little information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the expression:

[A wild guess:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wild%20guess)

> a guess based on no knowledge or information.

(M-W)

> - *It might be a wild guess, but Brasil will win this world cup.*

Answer (score 0):

**out in left field** (idiom)

> *US, informal*
>
> Very strange or unusual
>
> *Ideas that are out in left field*
>
> *Her position is was out in left field* [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/out%20in%20left%20field)

> In American English
> *Informal*
> Not reasonable, sensible, or probable
>
> *Slang*
> Completely mistaken; wrong
>
> Unusual and unconventional
> *Most of the business tips are common sense, but others are right out of left field.* [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/out-in-left-field)

Answer (score -1):

The metaphor **off the top of one's head** can have this meaning:

> *(right) off the top of one's head*
>
> Fig. without giving it too much thought or without precise knowledge.

[[McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/off+the+top+of+head)]

- *I might be talking off the top of my head, but Brasil are going to win this World Cup.*

Comment: That's not how that metaphor is used.  At least not in my experience

Comment: But it is in my experience. And according to the research carried out by the respected dictionary I cite. It's unscholarly to use oneself as a sole reference when a known authority conflicts with one's opinion.

Comment: Even your link doesn't support that.  "Off the top of my head" means the information you have readily at hand without doing research or thinking really deeply. It doesn't have anything to do with wild predictions. I've heard it used like: "What are the sales figures for last month?" "Off the top of my head, I don't know".  I've never heard anyone use it like "I'm gonna go off the top of my head and say that the Cleveland Browns are going to win the Super Bowl this year"

Comment: 'Is there an idiom for saying something that (a) might turn out wrong or ... ' ... _off the top of (one's) head_ [[Farlex Dictionary of Idioms](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/off+the+top+of+your+head)]
From memory or [b] **without much or careful consideration**.
_A: "How much can we expect to earn this quarter?" B: "Off the top of my head, it should be around $200,000, but I'll have to check the figures when I get to the office."_ Dictionaries research idiomaticity rather than allowing one person to give an opinion, off the top of their head.